# Highcharts Bar Chart - How to set the minimum bar width/length

Tags: jquery, highcharts

We're having issues throughout our application with bars not rendering if a particular value is very small relative to the largest value. The following jsFiddle illustrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/yahsukram/dQHQf/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: -50000,
            max: 5000000,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            categories: ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob', 'Bill', 'Jesus'],
            data: [5000000, 20000, 200, -50000, -10000]
        }]
    });
});
```

Note that the bars for 200 and -10000 do not render at all. Is there a way to set the minimum width to 2 or 3 pixels? I've tried several things and searched around but haven't found anything that really gets around the issue. We have quite a few different charts that exhibit this behavior and the upper/lower values can change drastically depending on what type of data we're fetching.

Increasing the width of the container is not an option as we're rending many charts in column format which gives us limited real estate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the option you want is minPointLength:

```
plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                minPointLength:5,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sigh. I completely missed that in the API documentation. Thanks for pointing that out... works perfectly.

Comment: Note that this will also show a bar even if the value is 0.  This is generally not desired.  Anyone know of a solution for that too?